# adding a length of time when creating table in oracle sql

Tags: sql, oracle

ive been asked to create a table that includes

Entry time (m.sshh) eg. 0.3506 (store as a number)
Final time (m.sshh) eg. 0.3506 (store as a number)

how do I format this when I create the table? I've tried

```
CREATE TABLE S_ENTRY
(
reg_code varchar(5),
event_no number(1,50),
entry_time number (m.sshh),
final_time number (m.sshh)
;
```

but I get a "numeric precision specifier is out of range (1 to 38)" error. I also get a missing right parenthesis error when I use to_char.

Thanks

Comment: What do you want to store exactly? Timestamps? Intervals? What is "m.sshh" supposed to stand for? If it's "minute.secondsecondhourhour", please explain why such an odd format.

Comment: I have no idea, just going back through the tutorial exercises. I want to store the currently unknown length that a swimmer completed a race, I guess if the m stands for minute its .3506 of a minute?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The basic answer is: do not store them as numbers.

You are looking for [Interval Literals](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/sql_elements003.htm#i38598), especially the `DAY TO SECOND` type ones.

Please read the linked documentation, you should get why it fits your needs.

Comment: It's a table for a swimming competition, and the example given is 0.3506 and I don't even know what that means, I guess 35 seconds and 0.6 milliseconds?

Answer (score 0):

This is not a great format.  But what you want is a fixed field, with defined scale and precision:

```
CREATE TABLE S_ENTRY (
    reg_code varchar(5),
    event_no number(1,50),
    entry_time number(6, 4),
    final_time number(6, 4)
);
```

You need to understand, though, that Oracle only sees these values as numbers.  If you want them stored as times, you can use `interval`:

```
entry_time interval day(0) to seconds(0)
```

You could also use a `timestamp` or `date` with the "date" component as 0, but `interval` makes more sense because it can be added to a date.